# How can I serialize a specific item from a list to JSON?

Tags: c#, serialization

How can I serialize a specific item in a list to JSON?

I have the JSON content below from which I need to create a new JSON with only product 2.
So I deserialize the JSON and then try to re-serialize it and create the new JSON content.

**JSON content 1:**

```
{
  "custId": 123, 
  "ordId": 4567, 
  "items":[
    {
      "prodId":77,
      "price"":70,
      "title":"Product 1"
    },
    {
      "prodId":78,
      "price"":95.99,
      "title":"Product 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Deserialized class from above JSON:**

```
class Item
{
    public int prodId { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

class Summary
{
    public int custId { get; set; }
    public int ordId { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

**How do I serialize the class with item[1] from the list?**

**New JSON content I need to create:**

```
{
  "custId": 123, 
  "ordId": 4567, 
  "items":[
    {
      "prodId":78,
      "price"":95.99,
      "title":"Product 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your current re-serialization code? How do you specify which item to keep? Is it a function? Show actual C# code and the solution will come quickly!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your code looks so here are a lot of assumptions.

Say you can deserialize/re-serialize the JSON object without further impediments. Between the two moments (deserialization and re-serialization) invoke the `Filter()` method I added below to the `Summary` class. This will remove all items but the one you want to keep.

```
class Summary
{
    public int custId { get; set; }
    public int ordId { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }

    public void Filter(int id)
    {
        int i;

        i = 0;
        while (i < items.Count)
        {
            if (items[i].prodId == id)
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To be clear about the usage of this method:

```
// deserialize
summary.Filter(id); // id is the ID of the item to keep
// re-serialize to JSON as you already do
```

I hope this makes any sense to you.